# System Font System and Desktop enviroment are extremely small after a reboot

Tags: kubuntu, display-resolution, bug-reporting

i am currently running kubuntu and just rebooted my computer to find everything like system font size, titlebar size and other desktop environment elements are all extremely small. Before the reset i added a second monitor but this was while my OS was running and didnt seem to effect the size of anything. I have been in the display config and messed around with a few things like resolution but that didn't help either.

ideas how i might fix this. Thanks

Image of what my desktop looks like
[image: Image of what my desktop looks like]

Answer (score 0):

This should be re-configurable in System Settings ⇢ Appearance ⇢ Fonts. Hopefully this gets the text back to a readable size for you

Comment: It not just the font size. Its everything, the desktop elements, titlebar, etc

Comment: It is Global Scale, not font size. And really this "extremely small" is a normal size with 100% zoom, where bottom pane is 36 px.

Comment: @N0rbert, i edited the global scale in screen display but it didnt do anything